# Virtual machine "pc1" Netkit error?

Tags: linux, debian, installation

**Introduction**

I've just installed a networking simulator Called *Netkit*. On *Debian stretch stable*. Using the official installation guide [here](http://wiki.netkit.org/download/netkit/INSTALL).

**Installation**

After setting the correct paths and installing. I then run the *check_configuration.sh* script.

Everything is checked OK, and it has found the terminal emulator xterm which is needed for netkit. And recieve the complete message.

> [ READY ] Congratulations! Your Netkit setup is now complete!
>             Enjoy Netkit!

**The Problem**

Running netkit using the command:

> vstart pc1

The xterm netkit-kernel emulator starts running. However I'm getting an infinite loop of the same error message:

> ubda: can't open "home/foo/netkit/pc1.disk" failed, errno= 13

So im guessing it's because the file is missing? if so how do i obtain it? and if not, what is causing this error. I've followed the install guide completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your system is not a 32bit system. Netkit is only supported on the 32-bit architecture(unless the compatibility libraries are installed). Hence I would suggest you download a 32-bit VM(instead of installing the libraries) and run Netkit on the same(worked fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

Check **position** of your lab-folder..

Comment: A more detailed answer would be helpful.